# java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: java

Проверяю метод для записи в csv файл. Остальные работают просто прекрасно, а вот конкретно этот показывает ошибку

```
ava.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
at ru.sfedu.mentalhelper.api.DataProviderCSVTest.lambda$createGoalSuccess$3(DataProviderCSVTest.java:607)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:104)
at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:593)
at ru.sfedu.mentalhelper.api.DataProviderCSVTest.createGoalSuccess(DataProviderCSVTest.java:606)
```

Сам метод:

```
public void createGoalSuccess() throws IOException {
    log.info("createGoalSuccess");
    File fileTests = new File(Constants.GOAL_PROPERTIES_CONST);
    Properties propertiesGoal = new Properties();
    propertiesGoal.load(new FileReader(fileTests));
    DataProviderCSV instance = new DataProviderCSV();
    IntStream.range(1,4).
            forEach(i -> {
                    assertTrue(instance.createGoal(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), propertiesGoal.getProperty(Constants.GOAL_CONST +i), Priority.MEDIUM));
            });
}
```

предполагаю, что проблема в том, что в данном методе есть енуменатор
версия csv 5.3

Comment: Ошибка потому что метод вернул `false`: `instance.createGoal(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), propertiesGoal.getProperty(Constants.GOAL_CONST +i),Priority.MEDIUM)`. Удачи с отладкой :)

Comment: @gil9red ну это понятно, но, другие методы, точно такие же, просто другая сигнатура выдают true, значит проблема конкретно в инуменаторе. Тут вопрос, как решить это?